# Why is if statement affecting the existence of private attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am practising python OOP and got stuck. `_filename` is clearly defined in `__init__` method but an error is raised. I don't know why.

```python
import os
import pickle
import sys

config_directory = 'configs/'   # added:  see below

class ConfigKeyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, this, key):
        self.key = key
        self.keys = this.keys()
    def __str__(self):
        return ('key "{0}" not found.  Available keys:' '({1})'.format(self.key, ', '.join(self.keys)))

class ConfigDict(dict):
    config_directory = 'configs/'
    def __init__(self, picklename):
        self._filename = config_directory + picklename + '.pickle'
        if not os.path.isfile(self._filename):
            with open(self._filename, 'wb') as fh:
                pickle.dump({}, fh)
        with open(self._filename, 'rb') as fh:
            config_content = pickle.load(fh)
            self.update(config_content)
            print(self._filename)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if not key in self:
            raise ConfigKeyError(self, key)
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        with open(self._filename, 'wb') as fh:
            pickle.dump(self, fh)


cd = ConfigDict('config_file')
print(cd._filename)
```

When I run this, the below error is raised.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assignment5.py", line 38, in <module>
    cd = ConfigDict('config_file')
  File "assignment5.py", line 23, in __init__
    config_content = pickle.load(fh)
  File "assignment5.py", line 34, in __setitem__
    with open(self._filename, 'wb') as fh:
AttributeError: 'ConfigDict' object has no attribute '_filename'
```

However, if I add the following if statement to the original code.

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
    if '_filename' in dir(self):
        with open(self._filename, 'wb') as fh:
            pickle.dump(self, fh)
```

The error disappeared and everything works well.

Summary:
Without if statement --> attribute '_filename' not found
With if statement --> attribute '_filename' found

Why is this happening?

Comment: Make sure you're using ASCII underscore everywhere. There are some Unicode characters that look like underscore.

Comment: The code you posted does not work (it throws a different exception than you claim it does). We'll need a [mcve].

Comment: I would use `self.config_directory` in stead of `config_directory` ?

Comment: I found the error is raised because of __setitem__ method? if I remove it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code in my system and it ran perfectly without any modification.

[image]

Can you please check if you have any other module which has same class `ConfigDict`? Maybe that module/class does not have given attribute and Python is picking up that class instead of this one.

Comment: @Shektar this belongs to a comment, not to an answer.

Comment: @bruno, thanks for comment, I wanted to show screenshot which is not possible to do as part of comment, hence added as answer.

Comment: Your screenshot is useless - just say that you ran the code on your system without issue, we don't need a proof.

Comment: Oh, that's good for me to know that it's nothing wrong in the code.